# Breeze child entities within observablearray not being created as "dependentobservable"

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

Hmm. Seems wrong to me.  I have a breeze query that does this:

```
             var query = new breeze.EntityQuery()
                     .from("AllGames")
                     .expand("Sets, MVP, TeamerMVP.Person")
                     .orderBy("GameDateTime desc");
```

(There can be none or many TeamerMVP records per game and there is a one to one relationship with the person table, hence the expand statement for TeamerMVP.Person so I can directly access the "Name" property in person.  This works perfectly in the directly one-to-one related MVP (of which there can only be one per game))

and all seems fine - the related entities are loaded and I can access the child entities in prototype functions alright as well.  However I get problems trying to do much within the html bindings with the child entities and, on checking in chrome's console, it appears it may be because the child entities, unlike the parent, are not declared as dependentobservable, they are just plain "objects".

```
viewmodel defines parent as:           games = ko.observableArray([])
```

Evaluation in console:

```
$data
    Object
        games: Object[0]
        _latestValue: Array[7]
        0: Game
        1: Game
        2: Game
            >GameDateTime: function dependentObservable() {
            >HomeGame: function dependentObservable() {
            >ID: function dependentObservable() {
            >LeagueGame: function dependentObservable() {
            >MVP: function dependentObservable() {
            >MVP_PersonID: function dependentObservable() {
            >NLorRL: "<strong>NL</strong> (A)"
            >Opponent: function dependentObservable() {
            >Sets: Object[0]
            >TeamerMVP: Object[0]
```

In the expanded node you can see that the parent entity-level properties (GameDateTime, HomeGame, etc.) are created as dependentobservables but the child entities (Sets, TeamerMVP) are not and I'm guessing this is why I'm having some trouble in the html template bindings doing things like "foreach" as knockout simply doesn't seem to see those child entities.

Is there something I'm missing?  Should I be creating a "games.Sets = ko.observableArray([])" declaration in the viewmodel to act as a container for the child entity when it's created?

The json data returned shows the following:

```
TeamerMVP: [{$id:20, $type:lbD.model.TeamerMVP, lbD.model, GameID:3, PersonID:4,…}]
    0: {$id:20, $type:lbD.model.TeamerMVP, lbD.model, GameID:3, PersonID:4,…}
    $id: "20"
    $type: "lbD.model.TeamerMVP, lbD.model"
    GameID: 3
    Person: {$id:21, $type:lbD.model.Person, lbD.model, ID:4, Name:Mike Connor, isAdmin:false,…}
    PersonID: 4
```

and it's easy to see the "Name" property within the related Person table.

Edited to add:
It's just the "TeamerMVP" relationship that is troublesome. Just managed to do something with a "forEach" on the "Sets" entity so that's working fine, even though it's not a dependentobservable.... I'm puzzled.

Further edited for Ward's question:

At breakpoint as requested I see these listed:

```
breezeConfig.manager.metadataStore._structuralTypeMap
Object
  >Game:#lbD.model: ctor
  >GameSet:#lbD.model: ctor
  >Person:#lbD.model: ctor
  >TeamerMVP:#lbD.model: ctor
  >Venue:#lbD.model: ctor
  >__proto__: Object
```

These are the concrete table names from my (simple) database.  If I expand "GameSet" then one of the properties is: defaultResourceName: "Sets" which is the navigation property name (defined in model as "Public Overridable Property Sets() As ICollection(Of GameSet)").

Ah... just expanded "TeamerMVP" and its defaultresourcename is "TeamerMVPs" which is a small but subtle difference!  I don't recall defining a version with the "s" on the end anywhere and a quick search of the project reveals no results.  Curious.  Maybe that's the issue, I'll have a quick play with the html bindings now.

Edit 3: HTML Bindings info

Nope, not playing ball at all...

I have this template:

```
 <script type="text/html" id="TeamerMVPTemplate">
    <div>Teamer MVP(s):&nbsp;</div>
    <li data-bind="text: Person().Name"></li>
</script>
```

Which is embedded in another template (the main "foreach: games" one) which is where it is referenced:

```
<span class="fixtureBoxLine" data-bind="template: { name: 'setScoresTemplate', foreach: Sets }"></span>
<span class="fixtureBoxLine" data-bind="template: { name: 'TeamerMVPTemplate', foreach: TeamerMVPs }"></span>
```

...and it just silently breaks. No error message but the processing stops on the first loop of the first game.  The "foreach: Sets" template immediately above it works perfectly.

If I change "foreach: TeamerMVPs" back to "foreach: TeamerMVP" in the binding declaration above, all games are processed but nothing is shown in the template for TeamerMVP so I guess "TeamerMVPs" is the correct entity reference and there's something odd going on with the way I'm trying to access it. Is "Person().Name" the correct binding in the template?

===========================================

Edit 4: Clarification of model

manager.metadataStore.getEntityType('Game').navigationProperties returns 4 navigation properties.  This is correct, there should be a collection of 0 to many "Sets", a collection of 0 to many "TeamerMVP", a 0 to one "MVP" and a 0 to one "Venue". All are present.

There can be only one (or none) MVP but it is entirely correct for there to be 0 to many TeamerMVP. This relationship is set up in exactly the same way as the "Sets" relationship that works.  The only slight difference being that the "TeamerMVP" tavle itself has a 1-to-1 relationship with the "Person" table as any TeamerMVP must be a valid person.  This is why my breeze query defines an "expand" that refers to "TeamerMVP.Person" and this appears to work as the json data returned is exactly as I would expect.   In the raw json, the navigation property is referred to as "TeamerMVP" and it is only in the "structuraltypemap" that the defaultResourceName is referred to as "TeamerMVPs".

If I leave the html binding as "forEach TeamerMVP" then all games are returned and bound to the "foreach games" parent template as expected, but no data are bound to the TeamerMVP template and no errors are shown in the console.  If I change the binding to "foreach TeamerMVPs" then only one game is returned and then processing stops at the point that the binding would occur and data would be shown.  No error is show in the console, however.

It appears as if breeze is creating the navigation property as "TeamerMVPs" internally and yet the json is returning "TeamerMVP" and maybe that disparity is why the binding appears to work and yet no data are bound?  It's way above my comprehension at present!

=================================================================

Edit 5: Add model information

**Game Model**

```
Public Class Game
    Public Property ID() As Integer
    Public Property GameDateTime() As System.DateTime
    Public Property Opponent() As String
    Public Property HomeGame() As Boolean
    Public Property LeagueGame() As Boolean
    Public Property MVP_PersonID() As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Public Property VenueID() As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Public Property isNL() As Boolean

    Public Overridable Property Sets() As ICollection(Of GameSet)
    Public Overridable Property MVP() As Person
    Public Overridable Property TeamerMVP() As ICollection(Of TeamerMVP)
    Public Overridable Property Venue() As Venue
End Class
```

**TeamerMVP Model**

```
Public Class TeamerMVP
    Public Property GameID() As Integer
    Public Property PersonID() As Integer

    Public Overridable Property Person() As Person
End Class
```

**Person Model**

```
Public Class Person
    Public Property ID() As Integer
    Public Property Name() As String
    Public Property isAdmin() As Boolean
    Public Property email() As String
    Public Property type() As String
    Public Property Image() As String
    Public Property thumbImage() As String
    Public Property backImage1() As String
    Public Property backImage2 As String
    Public Property Height() As String
    Public Property YearStarted() As String
    Public Property Position() As String
    Public Property PreviousClubs() As String
    Public Property ShirtNumber() As String
    Public Property isNL() As Boolean

    Public Overridable Property Games_MVP() As ICollection(Of Game)
    Public Overridable Property Games_TeamerMVP() As ICollection(Of Game)
End Class
```

**GameSet Model**

```
Public Class GameSet
    Public Property ID() As Integer
    Public Property GameID() As Integer
    Public Property SetNo() As Integer
    Public Property ourScore() As Integer
    Public Property theirScore() As Integer

    Public Overridable Property Game() As Game
End Class
```

Using `breezeConfig.manager.getEntities('TeamerMVP')` in the console at the success breakpoint does indeed reveal a whole load of "TeamerMVP" entities.  The network resource tab shows the correct related entities for "TeamerMVP" in the raw returned data too.

However, running `data.results[0].TeamerMVP()` in the console at the success breakpoint still returns nothing:

```
data.results[0].TeamerMVP()
>[]
data.results[2].TeamerMVP()
>[]
```

The first one above is correct, the first returned game has no associated "TeamerMVP" entities as yet, but the 3rd game in the sequence does have associated entitities as shown in the raw json data returned:

```
TeamerMVP: [{$id:4, $type:lbD.model.TeamerMVP, lbD.model, GameID:24, PersonID:14,…},…]
 >0: {$id:4, $type:lbD.model.TeamerMVP, lbD.model, GameID:24, PersonID:14,…}
 >1: {$id:6, $type:lbD.model.TeamerMVP, lbD.model, GameID:24, PersonID:15,…}
```

Comment: Apparently doesn't know that `Set` and `TeamerMVP` are entity types. Let's confirm if that is so: put a breakpoint on, say, the success callback from the first query. Then in the console enter: `manager.metadataStore._structuralTypeMap` (assume `manager` is your EM). This will list the types known on the client. Tell us if you see `Set` and `TeamerMVP`. If you do ... I'm surprised but we'll know where to start. If you don't, I'm suspecting a problem in your definition of the types on the server and in particular your EF mapping. We'll follow up there when you have an answer to my question.

Comment: @Ward Have edited question to add details. thanks.

Comment: @Ward edited again to add more info

Comment: Well at least we know that the Breeze client recognizes the types. You shouldn't assume that the `Game.Sets` is not observable. `Object[0]` is what a KO observable array looks like in the console. Expand it and you should see that that object has a `__ko_proto_` function. But if `Game.`TeamerMVP` is supposed to return a single  `TeamerMVP entity then something IS wrong because that should be a `function dependentObservable()`. See next comment.

Comment: Let's focus on `Game.TeamerMVP`. Breakpoint again and tell us what you've got in `manager.metadataStore.getEntityType('Game').navigationProperties`. Should be an array of 2 items, one describing `Game.Sets` and one describing `Game.TeamerMVP`. I bet you only have one navigation property ... the one for `Game.Sets`. Let us know and we'll take the next step.

Comment: WHOA!  Looking at your binding for TeamerMVP I'm confused. It has a "foreach" in it which implies that you are expecting multiple TeamerMVP items. But the `Game.TeamerMVP` property name is singular which usually indicates you're expecting 0-1 of them. Two comments ago I thought it was odd that `Game.TeamerMVP` was an `Object[0]` because I was expecting a reference navigation. But if you're really expecting a collection navigation (0-n TeamerMPVs) then `Object[0]` is correct and all will be well when you look at `Game`'s navigation Properties. But your foreach refers to "TeamerMPVs" PLURAL ???

Comment: Your `Game` type doesn't have a `TeamerMVPs` property so the foreach should fail ... loudly. I'm getting turned around. Please clarify (1) is `TeamerMVP` a scalar or collection navigation property of `Game` and (2) what does the `manager.metadataStore.getEntityType('Game').navigationProperties` say about each of the navigation properties. Now I'll wait.

Comment: @Ward Sorry for delay in response - it got late in the UK and I had to get to bed.  It's now 8am here for reference!  I don't expect to see you online until much later, thanks for the help.  "Edit 4" in the main question contains more details as requested.

Comment: One more question before I ask for repro. Put a breakpoint in your query success callback. What do you get from `data.results[0].TeamerMVP()` (`data.results[0]` is the first `Game`). Should get an array of `TeamerMVP`. Pick one. Does it have a `Person`? It should. If getting nothing try another item from either of the arrays (`results[]`, `TeamerMVP()`)

Comment: Would like to see the "TeamerMVPTemplate" too.

Comment: data.results[0].TeamerMVP()
[]

Comment: It's empty and yet in the network tab under the web service call there is data in TeamerMVP!

Comment: The TeamerMVPTemplate is right there above edit 4 - isn't that what you were asking for?

Comment: Just for info, data.results[0].Sets() results in an array of sets as expected. Both "Sets" and "TeamerMVP" look identical (Object[0]) in the game entity. I'm baffled.

Comment: @ward Just apologising in advance if you ask a question of me after about another half hour or so as I'll be in bed due to timezone differences and won't be able to respond until the morning.  Thanks for trying to help me though, it's much appreciated.

Comment: Very strange. Let's see if the `TeamerMVP` entities made it into cache. At same breakpoint try this: `manager.getEntities('TeamerMVP')`. That returns all instances of that entity type that are in cache. Btw, I overlooked the template; sorry. We'll pick up tomorrow.

Comment: Send server-side `Game` and `TeamerMVP` class definitions too please.

Comment: @Ward Thanks Ward, "Edit 5" has been done to original question above with lots more information added.

Comment: @Ward  I realise you've got loads of other stuff to be doing too but I'd really appreciate it if you could try and offer any insight on what I hope is the last piece of the puzzle. Whether it's a bug or (more likely) my stupidity in setting it up!

Comment: I've run out of ideas from this distance. Could you put it (or a stripped down version) in a [GitHub Gist](https://github.com/blog/1276-welcome-to-a-new-gist) ... and let me know how to contact you off S.O. with an email to breeze at ideablade dot com

Comment: @Ward just to say I've emailed things to you, hopefully they've arrived now!

Comment: Carl .. I didn't get that email

Comment: @Ward - have tried again with the "info" address from your website.

Answer (score 1):

**Final Update**

Wow, what can I say but huge thanks to Ward from Ideablade for devoting so much time to helping solve this problem.  It turned out, in the end, to be the simplest of things: a missing return navigation property from the dependent "TeamerMVP" to the parent "Game".

So all I had to do was change the TeamerMVP model from:

```
Public Class TeamerMVP
    Public Property GameID() As Integer
    Public Property PersonID() As Integer

    Public Overridable Property Person() As Person
End Class
```

To:

```
Public Class TeamerMVP
    Public Property GameID() As Integer
    Public Property PersonID() As Integer

    Public Overridable Property Game() As Game
    Public Overridable Property Person() As Person
End Class
```

...and all immediately came to life with the TeamerMVP entities appearing where they should.

Ward and his colleagues at Ideablade are looking into any possibilities of highlighting/trapping this situation if possible.  If you're reading this question as a beginner/trying to find out more about Breeze then I can only encourage you to try it out in full as it's an amazing product and I've only just scratched the surface of what it can do so far. Most importantly it has a great team behind it. Thanks Ward!